# How to get Genie (Automated UI Tester For ActionScript) to work?

Tags: apache-flex, automation, flash

I've tried installing Genie and followed the user guide. I'm not getting the Genie green icon on any swf's I run in the browsers.

In Eclipse, going to Genie -> About Genie shows that the Swf Lib and Executor fields are "unknown".

Also, the buttons on the top right are all dimmed except "Capture Image for UI Based Actions on Desktop".

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Genie\Genie Expressions gives the error:
"Plug-in GeniePlugin was unable to load class com.adobe.geniePlugin.views.GenieWatchView."

Comment: I never heard of Genie before.  Is this what you're using: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/ ?  It looks like they removed the "Genie" name except in the URL.  Are you sure you're using the latest version?

Comment: yes, I've been at it for only a few days now.. I've actually tried looking for an older version (maybe more stable) and couldn't find it

Comment: nevermind for some obscure reason i got it to work, not on all apps though

Comment: If you can formally answer your own question; I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding genie plugin jars to eclipse plugin folder. and add mm.cfg file to Admin/user folder. just start server and go ahead.